# Java reading text file with delimiter and pushing into an array

Tags: java, arrays, delimiter, csv

I am reading a file which has a delimiter between elements. I am trying to put each element into a new index of an array. This does not seem to work properly, everything seems to end up on one index of the array. Below is a sample text file and my code.

Textfile

```
%User  %James %Fields %Will Smith %sBel %James %Fields %Will Smith %sBel %James %Fields %Will Smith %sBel%James %Fields %Will Smith %sBel %James %Fields %Will Smith %sBel %James %Fields %Will Smith %sBel %James %Fields %Will Smith %sBel %James %Fields %Will Smith %sBel %James %Fields %Will Smith %sBel %James %Fields %Will Smith %sBel %James %Fields %Will Smith %sBel %James %Fields %Will Smith %sBel %James %Fields %Will Smith %sBel %James %Fields %Will Smith %sBel %James %Fields %Will Smith %sBel %James %Fields %Will Smith %sBel %James %Fields %Will Smith %sBel
```

Code

```
final InputStream i = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.users);
final Scanner s = new Scanner(i);
try
{
    while (s.hasNextLine())
    {
        String d = s.nextLine();
        String test;

        test = values[1];           
        userTextArea.append(test);
        test = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your code... If you need to put it in an array, you need to take your line  and use a stringtokenizer with % as delimiter. Then you need to create a an array String[] myStringArray = new String[tokenizer.countTokens()] in order to create you array with the number of tokens found;

Answer (score 0):

```
final InputStream i = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.users);
final Scanner s = new Scanner(i);
try
{
     while (s.hasNextLine())
    {
        String d = s.nextLine();
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(d,"%");
        String[] myStringArray = new String[st.countTokens()]

        int index = 0;
        while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            myStringArray[index] = st.nextElement();
            index ++;
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the split function.

```
String tmp = "%hallo %world";
String [] strArray = tmp.split("%");
System.out.print(strArray[0]); //prints hallo
```

Answer (score 0):

An array is a container object that holds a fixed number of values stored in unique indexes (positions).

**Causes**

> everything seems to end up on one index of the array

It will do, for *two* reasons:

1. The file you are reading in has no new-line characters. It will therefore assign *all* of the file contents to the variable "*d*" when you call *nextLine()*.

   ```
       String d = s.nextLine();
   ```

   To clarify, at this point in your program, "*d*" holds your whole text file.
2. Even if it did have new-line characters, you still wouldn't be reading anything into an array. After assigning the string to the variable "*d*". You are not doing anything with it.

**Suggestions**

One way of doing this would be to:

- Read the file as you are, as a single line and then use the String
  *split()* function to split elements, this function returns an array so you need to assign it to a *String[] array* variable. *Omit the
  while loop* as you only need to read a single line. After this, loop
  through the string array and append the values to the text area:

  ```
     String d = s.nextLine();
     String[] values = d.split("%");

     for(String value: values) {
        userTextArea.append(value.trim());
     }
  ```

  When appending, don't forget to trim the string because your file contains spaces between elements. The String *trim()* function will remove these.